# Defender of the Crown - Amiga version

Tags: amiga, defender-of-the-crown

In the **Amiga version** of the classic game "Defender of the Crown" you can build castles to protect your borders against invaders, but I never found out how to put soldiers into those castles. I only saw the effect that, if a county sporting such a stronghold got conquered by the enemy, all soldiers in the campaign army deserted, which renders building those expensive castles a high risk opportunity to show off superfluous wealth.

So, here's the question: is there a way to assign soldiers, knights and/or catapults to castles?